# order_by() not working when called on function which returns QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a problem getting my django ordering to work. When I define a function in a model definition which returns a QuerySet with `order_by()` called on it I get the correct order. However, when I call `order_by()` outside of the definition I do not get the correct order.

#### working code:

The following orders the 'parts' correctly by name:

```
# models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, default=0)
    ...
    def get_parts_as_owner(self):
        user=self.user
        return Part.objects.filter(Q(owner=user)).order_by('name')

class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45,unique=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

# views.py
def view_parts(request):
    user = request.user
    owned = user.get_profile().get_parts_as_owner()
    return render_to_response('parts/view_parts.html', {'owned': owned}, RequestContext(request))
```

#### not working code:

the following does not order as I would expect (by name):

```
# models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, default=0)
    ...
    def get_parts_as_owner(self):
        user=self.user
        return Part.objects.filter(Q(owner=user))

class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45,unique=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

# views.py
def view_parts(request):
    user = request.user
    owned = user.get_profile().get_parts_as_owner().order_by('name')
    return render_to_response('parts/view_parts.html', {'owned': owned}, RequestContext(request))
```

#### also not working

The following orders by name and not by last_modified, which I would expect

```
# models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, default=0)
    ...
    def get_parts_as_owner(self,order='name'):
        user=self.user
        return Part.objects.filter(Q(owner=user)).order_by(order)

class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45,unique=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

# views.py
def view_parts(request):
    user = request.user
    owned = user.get_profile().get_parts_as_owner(order='last_modified')
    return render_to_response('parts/view_parts.html', {'owned': owned}, RequestContext(request))
```

Why are these not ordering as I would expect? What is the difference in when I call `order_by`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the related managers instead of creating methods on the model to return an entirely new queryset. For example, to get the user's parts, you need only do:

```
request.user.get_profile().part_set.order_by('name')
```

This is built-in for you. There's no need to do anything else.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am also creating additional methods on the models which return more complex querysets such as `def get_parts_as_shared(self):
        user=self.user
        sg = ShareGroup.objects.filter(members__in=[user])
        return list(set(Part.objects.filter(sharers__in=sg)))` how would that affect it?

Comment: Also, this does not answer why would they not order correctly from what I have done?